# If the order of growth of a process is `log3 a`, can we simplify it to `log a`?

Tags: sicp

I'm learning the book [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.3), and for the exercise 1.15:

```
Exercise 1.15.  The sine of an angle (specified in radians) can be computed by making use of the approximation sin x  x if x is sufficiently small, and the trigonometric identity


to reduce the size of the argument of sin. (For purposes of this exercise an angle is considered ``sufficiently small'' if its magnitude is not greater than 0.1 radians.) These ideas are incorporated in the following procedures:

(define (cube x) (* x x x))
(define (p x) (- (* 3 x) (* 4 (cube x))))
(define (sine angle)
   (if (not (> (abs angle) 0.1))
       angle
       (p (sine (/ angle 3.0)))))

a.  How many times is the procedure p applied when (sine 12.15) is evaluated?

b.  What is the order of growth in space and number of steps (as a function of a) used by the process generated by the sine procedure when (sine a) is evaluated?
```

I get the answer of the "order of growth in number of steps" by myself is **log<sub>3</sub> a**. But I found something say, the constants in the expression can be ignored, so it's the same as **log a**, which looks simpler.

I understand the **2n** can be simplified to **n**, and **2n<sup>2</sup> + 1** can be simplified to **n<sup>2</sup>**, but not sure if this is applied to **log<sub>3</sub> a** too.

Comment: "Constants that can be ignored" are the C in `C * O(..)`, eg. `C * O(lg3(n))` -> `O(lg3(n))` - the subscript/superscript in the examples pertains to the function involving n, not a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (since we're just interested in the order of the number of steps, not the exact number of steps)

Consider the formula for [changing the base of a logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Change_of_Base_of_Logarithm):

log<sub>b</sub>(x) = log<sub>a</sub>(x) / log<sub>a</sub>(b)

In other words you can rewrite log<sub>3</sub>(a) as:

log<sub>3</sub>(a) = log<sub>10</sub>(a) / log<sub>10</sub>(3)

Since log<sub>10</sub>(3) is just a constant, then for the order of growth we are only interested in the log<sub>10</sub>(a) term.